# Java Excel data upload in java error in org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I tried to do an excel data upload into a database using Apache.POI. their function gives me an error like

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The code segment error occurs in

```
for (Iterator iterator = dataHolder.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        List list = (List) iterator.next();
         i++;
        if (i > 0) {  
            ID =  (int) list.get(0);
            Employee_Number = list.get(1).toString();
            FirstName = list.get(2).toString();
            LastName = list.get(3).toString();
            EmailAddress = list.get(4).toString();
            PdfName = list.get(5).toString();
            Sup_EmailAddress = list.get(6).toString();
            PassCode = list.get(7).toString();
```

can anyone suggest me why getting this kind of error?.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official JavaDoc of XSSFCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html) you can use `getNumericCellValue()` instead.

> `public double getNumericCellValue()`
>
> Get the value of the cell as a number.

To safely check whether you process an actual number, you can re-write your code fragment as follows:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;

int ID;
// ... loop here ...
    XSSFCell cell = list.get(0);
    if(CellType.NUMERIC == cell.getCellType()) {
        ID =  new Double(cell.getNumericCellValue()).intValue(); 
    } else {
        // handle this case separately... 
    }
// end loop
```

The above code snippet avoids unnecessary casts and/or try and error guessing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You shold mention in what `apache poi` version `XSSFCell.getCellType` returns a `CellType`. In latest stable release Apache POI 3.17 [XSSFCell.getCellType](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java?view=markup#l675) returns an `int`. There `XSSFCell.getCellTypeEnum` is needed to get a `CellType`.

Comment: That's a useful hint. I relied on the latest public JavaDoc as linked in the answer. In this version, `getCellType()` is not marked as deprecated, however, `getCellTypeEnum()` is marked as deprecated. Quite confusing, isn't it? The linked JavaDoc version states "Deprecated. use getCellType instead".

Comment: Yes this is confusing. The `apache poi` programmers are updating the latest public JavaDoc always to be the JavaDoc for the currently nightly build instead of the latest stable version. Many users are confused about this. And professional users will definitely not using any nightly build in productive usage. So always own JavaDocs are necessary from downloaded source.

Answer (score 0):

The line `ID =  (int) list.get(0);` throws an error because the data in the cell cannot be converted to an int. Try to save it as a String.

```
id = (String) list.get(0);
```

Or as a long

```
id = (long) list.get(0);
```

Or handle the exception

```
try {
  ID = (int) list.get(0);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  // id is not a number
}
```

Comment: are not there any other way to keep it as a int value?

Comment: You cannot save a value as a number if it's not a number. But you can skip it if you don't need it by handling the exception.